# PHP: is this a bug: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object that implements the ArrayableInterface (BTW, it's from Laravel's Eloquent ORM).

This object is $articles. So naturally, I can do this:

```
foreach ($articles as $article)
    echo $article->title . "<br/>";
```

But **I can't do this:**

```
shuffle($articles);
```

I get the `shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given` warning.

Comment: It's probably an unimplemented feature more than a bug. Such is life in phpsia.

Comment: shuffle() used for array your entered an object...

Comment: No, it's not a bug, an object is still an object, even it behaves like an array. PHP's `array_*` functions don't work with objects for the same reason. (btw, Arrayable? really? whatever next, Objectable? )

Comment: @Crisp Maybe it would be called "Objectionable". :)

Comment: @Barmar certainly seems apt ;)

Comment: @Crisp why does `sort($articles)` work then?

Comment: @duality_ define 'works'? It raises the following warning `Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given` and the object is not sorted.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `usort($articles, function($article) {return $article['clicks'];})`.

Comment: @duality_ and usort returns the same warning `Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given` and the object is not sorted.

Comment: I guess you're right. I seem to remember that I was able to do that, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a bug.

PHP 5 allows you to use `foreach()` to loop through objects that aren't arrays. These objects are called `Iterators`.

Unfortunately, the old array-based functions, like `shuffle()` cannot process Iterators.

The main reason for this is that an Iterator may not even be sortable -- for example, you can have iterators that read directly from a file or a URL, and read a new line of data each time the `foreach()` loop cycles. This clearly can't be sorted because it's read during the `foreach()` process.

You can convert an Iterator into an array, using the cleverly named [`iterator_to_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) function. However, this may be a bad idea if you don't know how much data the iterator is going to process, as you may find it uses a lot of memory.

Some iterators may provide methods within the iterator object itself for sorting or filtering the data. If so, this is a better solution than trying to sort it as an array.

If you're working with an ORM, then this implies that your Iterator object is reading data from a DB. In this case, sorting it via the DB query (ie `ORDER BY` or whatever methods the ORM provides to do that) would probably be a better solution than sorting the data in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the interface does.. but nor will the shuffle function because it only recognises arrays. You'd need to do this:

```
$array = iterator_to_array($articles);
$shuffled = shuffle($array);
```

From an OOP perspective, really, your object should contain the shuffle implementation:

```
 $articles->shuffle();
```

Comment: your example return just true value not a collection of array